# case insensitive issue while fetching records from child table using HQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql, case-insensitive

I have a parent table and a child table where I am only getting 1 record from child table but not getting case insensitive matched record which is a mixed string. I am expecting it should return 2 records.

Below is the code for the same.

```sql
//parent Table
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "employeeID")
  private String employeeID;

  @Column(name = "name_first")
  private String nameFirst;

  @Column(name = "name_last")
  private String nameLast;

}

//Child Table
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_salary")
public class EmployeeSalary implements Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private EmployeeSalaryPK employeeSalaryPKCompositeKey;

  @Column(name = "salaryBracket")
  private String salaryBracket;

}

@Embeddable
public class EmployeeSalaryPK implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "employeeID")
  private String employeeID;

  @Column(name = "salary")
  private String salary;

}
```

In employee_salary table I have two records (as shown below) but while fetching it using HQL only one record is coming with an actual match but case insensitive record is not coming.

> Employee Record:-   ABC  John  Kramer
>
> employee_salary table record:-
>
> ABC  100900
>
> aBc  76770

I am using simple HQL query (see below code) but getting only first record whenever I want to get both record as employeeID is abc.

```sql
String hqlQuery = " FROM " + Employee.class.getName() + " E WHERE E.employeeID= :EMPLOYEEID";
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
List<?> responseList = session.createQuery(hqlQuery).setParameter("EMPLOYEEID", "ABC").list();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all entities by case insensetive String id you have to convert id to same case (`lowercase` or `uppercase`) on both sides of the **WHERE clause** equality operator

```
String hqlQuery = " FROM " + Employee.class.getName() + " E WHERE lower(E.employeeID) = :EMPLOYEEID";
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
List<?> responseList = session.createQuery(hqlQuery).setParameter("EMPLOYEEID", "ABC".toLowerCase()).list();
```

Comment: it will not return mixed number as I want to get all combination like APB, abc and AbC.

Comment: Did you change **WHERE clause** this way `lower(E.employeeID) = :EMPLOYEEID`?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it